# What is wrong with the following code segment, and isn't default switch mandatory for "switch" loops?

Tags: c, switch-statement, label

I am tired of my university, my midterm exams and I am tired of thinking what the hell is wrong here.

```
double n;
n = 3.5; // line 2
switch( n){
case 2.5 : printf(“High”); break;
case 0.5 : printf(”Low”); break;}
```

In general, I thought default statement is missing because n is 3.5 and every switch statement we wrote included a default statement.

Options are:

- I)default statement is missing (What I ticked.)

  II)there is an error in line 2

  III)semi colon is missing at the end of the switch statement

  IV)double data type cannot be used with switch statement (Correct
  answer.)

Can anyone explain me why IV is correct answer? Thank you.

Comment: switch works on integral values.

Comment: IV is the correct answer because that's the way the C language is defined.  Simple as that.

Comment: Tip: It's a switch *statement*, not a switch *loop*. It's not a loop since it doesn't cause code to be executed repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

The label `default` may be omitted in the `switch` statement. However the `case` labels shall be of integer type.

So the `switch` statement is incorrect at least due to incorrect `case` labels.

Also the expression in the `switch` statement shall have an integer or an enumeration type.

Comment: Too many little details to memorize, too many frustrating things to encounter... Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

switch work on integral values (int, enum).

If you want to "switch" on double values, you will need to use if/else statements.